# To get the id of the control in javascript which is created by asp.net at runtime

Tags: asp.net, webforms

How to get the id of control which is created at run time in asp.net. I want to get that Id in javascript.

the actual id which I am setting is ctus_txtFirstName

at run-time the id is MainContent_ctus_txtfirstName

Answer (score 3):

Use the server control's `ClientID` property. It'll output the correct ID, containing the  fully qualified *Naming Container*.

```
<script>
    var ctrl = document.getElementById('<%= txtFirstName.ClientID %>');

    console.log(ctrl.value);
<script>
```

This is only applicable if you're using server controls. Plain markup will not have a Naming Container, if the `runat="server"` attribute is omitted.